# How to know the methods I should implement in a class that extends another class

Tags: android, inheritance, interface, adapter

I have this class

```
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter { }
```

I got an error if I don't implement some methods, like getCount()

The error is:

> The type AdapterListView must implement the inherited abstract method
>   Adapter.getCount()

The `BaseAdapter` class implements `ListAdapter` and `SpinnerAdapter`. These interfaces inherites methods from the `Adapter` interface, but this interface has the following abstract methods:

- getCount ()
- getItem ()
- getItemId ()
- getItemViewType ()
- getView ()
- getViewTypeCount ()
- hasStableIds ()
- isEmpty ()
- registerDataSetObserver ()
- unregisterDataSetObserver ()

See [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) interface for more details.

But I just implement getCount(), getItem(), getItemId(), getView(). And the compiler does not give this error. Why this happens?

Comment: your post is very confusing! I got an error if I don't implement some methods, like getCount() VS But I just implement getCount(), ... Anyway u can Eclipse let that do for you. Create a class extend a abstract one and save. Hover over the Classname marked in Red, and just click on "implement methods". Otherwise just look inside their Class-definitions, for  your particular class like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: I think it is not confusing. I said if I don't implement I got the error. But I implement the method. :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don'y need to implement these methods is that they are already implemented in the abstract class `BaseAdapter`.

See link with source code: [BaseAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java)

A class type `abstract` can implement some of the methods and leave some to be implemented for the class that extends it.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was very useful for me. And thank you too for this link.

Comment: That is, the BaseAdapter class does not implement the getCount(), getItem(), getItemId() and getView() methods. So I have to implement these  methods at my AdapterListView class.

Comment: Glad to help. Congratulations for your question, that shows a real interest in undestunding things.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend a class you don't need to implement all the methods of this class. Some methods must be at least declared like in your case getCount(), getId() etc and you can also override them if desired. In Eclipse you can see which methods must be declared when you hover a class name and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

dont chang names of these methods

getCount ();

getItem ();

getItemId ();

getItemViewType ();

getView ();

getViewTypeCount ();